# HTTPS Request in a Node express route

Tags: node.js, express, routes, http-get

I tried to get a result of a https request in a route in node express but it fails with the reason: connect ETIMEOUT. Any Idea where I'm wrong?

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    result = await https.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY');
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**
The URL is valid and does return something when pasted in browser,

Other endpoints in my API work fine, but they don't have a http request thought. They look like this i.e:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.sendFile("\\\\abc.local\\a$\\b$\\xyz\\001-005-877.pdf");
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ err: err.toString() });
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**
For completion:
I had a typo in my index.js/ routing (app.use("/test", require("./routes/test")); which caused the timeout. 
Then used this code:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  request('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log('body:', body);
  })
});
```

I used the module 'request'. as **Dijkstra** suggested and even though his code (for express default http requests) wasn't working for me, he still provided everything needed to solve the problem, so Thank you.

Comment: Whether that URL is returning data??

Comment: Try hitting the same url in browser or postman and see is it returning anything!

Comment: Yea, the URL is valid and does return data.

Comment: Try out request package https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not how `https.get()` works. Documentation is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback).

Possible implementation:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  https.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', (result) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    const data = '';
    result.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    result.on('end', () => {
      res.send(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
});
```

This is pretty complex code to perform such typical task. That is why there are popular packages to handle all the complex part behind the scene. I prefer to use [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Comment: I tried your code and it still times out. Thank you though, I will read the Documentation again and I installed request. Will try it with request and report back.

Comment: Its the same with request... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is something not right with your api endpoint I believe.

Comment: Well, other endpoints work fine in my API, but they dont have a http request though.

Comment: There was a mistake in the routing, thats why other routes worked and this one not. It's still not working as intended, but at least I get something to work with now. Thank you for your help.